# An easy to implement prolog graphical interface

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

So, I have a college project now that uses Prolog, I'm not the first one to work on the code so it's already pretty huge, but I have to put it working with a Prolog graphical interface, so my question is: is there any Prolog graphical interface that doesn't require me to change the code that's already written?

Comment: XPCE is pretty functional, but the learning curve is step

Comment: I recall writing Reversi game with "AI" in Prolog and a fancy graphical UI in C#. Swi have the libraries to support the interoperation.

Comment: @GuyCoder: referring to `needed examples`: not really, the best is the IDE itself: open it ( ` ?- edit(append).`) and then follow the menu `Help \ Xpce manual`. It opens a full learning environment for XPCE. I think it's very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you might want to look into:

https://www.gtk-server.org

Answer (score -1):

Besides SWI-Prolog own XPCE GUI toolkit, as mentioned in the comments, another possibility is to write the GUI in Java and use the SWI-Prolog JPL library to interface with it. The SWI-Prolog distribution includes some JPL examples that showcase GUI elements.

Adding a GUI interface to what, I assume, is currently a command-line application, will be facilitated if the Prolog application is already abstracting I/O using mechanisms such as the message printing mechanism. If that's already the case, the messages being printed can be intercepted using a hook predicate to display them in GUI elements.